# Solving $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sin^{2n}(x) + \cos^{2n}(x)}\:dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function, trigonometric-integrals, beta-function

Spurred on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3037919/evaluating-int-frac15s-8-9s-10-7s-12-2s-14-rm-dx-where) I decided to investigate the following integral:

\begin{equation}
 I_n = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sin^{2n}(x) + \cos^{2n}(x)}\:dx
\end{equation}

Where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

The approach I've taken is rather simple and whilst I've arrived at a closed form solution, I'm wondering whether the resultant sum can be expressed in terms of (non)-elementary functions. Would love to see other methods that can be used to solve this! (Using any methods).

First:

\begin{equation}
 I_n = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sin^{2n}(x) + \cos^{2n}(x)}\:dx = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\left[\sin^{2}(x)\right]^n + \left[\cos^{2}(x)\right]^n}\:dx
\end{equation}

Using the [Double-Angle Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html):

\begin{equation}
  \sin^2(x) = \frac{1 - \cos\left(2x\right)}{2} \qquad \cos^2(x) = \frac{1 + \cos\left(2x\right)}{2}
\end{equation}

Thus:

\begin{align}
 I_n &= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\left[\sin^{2}(x)\right]^n + \left[\cos^{2}(x)\right]^n}\:dx = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\left[\frac{1 - \cos\left(2x\right)}{2}\right]^n + \left[\frac{1 + \cos\left(2x\right)}{2}\right]^n}\:dx \\
&= 2^n \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\left[1 - \cos\left(2x\right)\right]^n + \left[1 + \cos\left(2x\right)\right]^n}\:dx
\end{align}

Making the substitution $u = 2x$

\begin{equation}
I_n = 2^n \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\left[1 - \cos\left(2x\right)\right]^n + \left[1 + \cos\left(2x\right)\right]^n}\:dx =  2^{n - 1} \int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{\left[1 - \cos\left(u\right)\right]^n + \left[1 + \cos\left(u\right)\right]^n}\:du
\end{equation}

Now apply the [Weierstrass (/Tangent half angle) substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) $t = \tan\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)$:

\begin{align}
I_n &=  2^{n - 1} \int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{\left[1 - \cos\left(u\right)\right]^n + \left[1 + \cos\left(u\right)\right]^n}\:du =  2^{n - 1} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left[1 - \frac{1 - t^2}{1 + t^2}\right]^n + \left[1 + \frac{1 - t^2}{1 + t^2}\right]^n} \frac{2\:dt}{t^2 + 1} \\
&=   \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\left[1 + t^2 \right]^{n - 1}}{t^{2n} + 1}\:dt
 \end{align}

By the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem):

\begin{equation}
 \left[1 + t^2 \right]^{2n - 1} = \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {n - 1 \choose j}t^{2j}
\end{equation}

Thus:
\begin{align}
I_n &=  \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\left[1 + t^2 \right]^{2n - 1}}{t^{2n} + 1}\:dt = \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {n - 1 \choose j} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{2j}}{t^{2n} + 1}
\end{align}

Using the solution I found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057298/solving-used-real-based-methods-int-0x-fractk-lefttn-a-rightm-d) we find:

\begin{align}
I_n &=   \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {n - 1 \choose j} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{2j}}{t^{2n} + 1} = \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {n - 1 \choose j} \cdot \frac{1}{2n} \cdot 1^{\frac{2j + 1}{2n} - 1}B\left(1 - \frac{2j + 1}{2n} , \frac{2j + 1}{2n}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2n}\sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {n - 1 \choose j} B\left(1 - \frac{2j + 1}{2n} , \frac{2j + 1}{2n}\right)
\end{align}

Using the [relationship between the Beta and Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_between_gamma_function_and_beta_function):

\begin{align}
I_n &= \frac{1}{2n}\sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {n - 1 \choose j} B\left(1 - \frac{2j + 1}{2n} , \frac{2j + 1}{2n}\right) = \frac{1}{2n}\sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {n - 1 \choose j} \frac{\Gamma\left(1 - \frac{2j + 1}{2n}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{2j + 1}{2n}\right)}{\Gamma\left(1 - \frac{2j + 1}{2n} + \frac{2j + 1}{2n}\right)} \\
&= \frac{1}{2n}\sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {n - 1 \choose j}\Gamma\left(1 - \frac{2j + 1}{2n}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{2j + 1}{2n}\right)
\end{align}

As $\frac{2j + 1}{2n} \not \in \mathbb{Z}$ we can employ [Euler's Reflection Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) to yield:

\begin{align}
I_n &= \frac{1}{2n}\sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {n - 1 \choose j}\Gamma\left(1 - \frac{2j + 1}{2n}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{2j + 1}{2n}\right) = \frac{1}{2n}\sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {n - 1 \choose j} \frac{\pi}{\sin\left(\pi \cdot \frac{2j + 1}{2n}\right)} \\&= \frac{\pi}{2n}\sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {n - 1 \choose j} \operatorname{cosec}\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\left(2j + 1\right) \right)
\end{align}

Thus,

\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sin^{2n}(x) + \cos^{2n}(x)}\:dx = \frac{\pi}{2n}\sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {n - 1 \choose j} \operatorname{cosec}\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\left(2j + 1\right) \right)
\end{equation}

Edit - Realised that $2n - 1$ should be $n - 1$

**Extra Addition:**

Using the same method as above an by letting 
\begin{equation}
 S_n(x) = \sin^{2n}(x) + \cos^{2n}(x)
\end{equation}

It becomes rather easy to solve:

\begin{equation}
 I_{n,m} = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{S_n(x)}{S_m(x)}\:dx
\end{equation}

Where $n \lt m$. After applying the double angle formulas, $u$-substitution, and half tangent formula we arrive at:

\begin{equation}
 I_{n,m} = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{S_n(x)}{S_m(x)}\:dx = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{2n} + 1}{t^{2m} + 1} \left[1 + t^2 \right]^{m - n - 1}\:dt
\end{equation}

Applying the Binomial Expansion:

\begin{align}
 I_{n,m} &=  \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {m - n - 1 \choose j} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{2n} + 1}{t^{2m} + 1} \cdot t^{2j}\:dt \\
&= \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {m - n - 1 \choose j} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{2\left(n + j\right)} }{t^{2m} + 1} \:dt + \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {m - n - 1 \choose j} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{2j} }{t^{2m} + 1} \:dt\\
\end{align}

Again applying another of my solutions (referenced above) we arrive at:

\begin{align}
 I_{n,m} &= \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {m - n - 1 \choose j} \frac{\pi}{2m}\operatorname{cosec}\left(\frac{\pi}{2m}\left(2\left(n + j\right) + 1\right) \right) + \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {m - n - 1 \choose j}\frac{\pi}{2m}\operatorname{cosec}\left(\frac{\pi}{2m}\left(2j + 1\right) \right) \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2m}\sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} {m - n - 1 \choose j}\left[\operatorname{cosec}\left(\frac{\pi}{2m}\left(2\left(n + j\right) + 1\right) \right) + \operatorname{cosec}\left(\frac{\pi}{2m}\left(2j + 1\right) \right) \right]
\end{align}

---

Note: Using the same method we can easily solve

\begin{equation}
 I_{n,p} = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\left(\sin^{2n}(x) + \cos^{2n}(x) \right)^p}\:dx = \frac{1}{2n\Gamma(p)}\sum_{m = 0}^{np - 1} {np - 1 \choose m}\Gamma\left(p - \frac{2m + 1}{2n}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{2m + 1}{2n}\right)
\end{equation}
Where $p \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: I think that's the "closest" you can reach to the "closed form"

Comment: @Digamma - Thanks. Let me know if you think of anything :-)

Comment: Wikipedia defines "a closed-form expression is a mathematical expression that can be evaluated in a finite number of operations." So if $n$ is finite, you have a closed form. Bravo David, this one is really spectacular.

Comment: Thanks @clathratus!.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot seem to add much here other than a slightly quicker way for you to reach the integral you arrive at after making a tangent half-angle substitution.

Factoring out a $\cos^{2n} x$ term in the denominator of the original integral for $I_n$ we have
$$I_n = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sec^{2n} x}{1 + \tan^{2n} x} \, dx = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sec^{2n - 2} x}{1 + \tan^{2n} x} \sec^2 x \, dx.$$
On setting $t = \tan x, dt = \sec^2 x \, dx$, we have
$$I_n = \int_0^\infty \frac{(1 + t^2)^{n - 1}}{1 + t^{2n}} \, dt.$$

Comment: Thanks @omegadot - Yes a much quicker way than the approach I took.

Answer (score 1):

The closed form for $$I_n=
\frac{\pi}{4} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d x}{\sin ^{2n} x+\cos ^{2n} x}
$$
is

$$
\boxed{I_{n}=\frac{\pi^2}{8 n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
n-1 \\
k
\end{array}\right) \csc \frac{(2 k+1) \pi}{2 n}}
$$

---

Proof:

Letting $t=\tan x$ yields $$
\begin{aligned}
I_{n} &=\frac{\pi}{4} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(1+t^{2}\right)^{n-1}}{t^{2 n}+1} \\
&= \frac{\pi}{4} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
n-1 \\
k
\end{array}\right) \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{2 k}}{t^{2 n}+1} d t .
\end{aligned}
$$

By my [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4397733/732917), $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{r}}{x^{m}+1} d x=\frac{\pi}{m} \csc \frac{(r+1) \pi}{m},$$

We can now get its closed form: $$
\boxed{I_{n}=\frac{\pi^2}{8 n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
n-1 \\
k
\end{array}\right) \csc \frac{(2 k+1) \pi}{2 n}}
$$

For examples:

\begin{aligned}
I_{2}&=\frac{\pi^2}{16}\left(\csc \frac{\pi}{4}+\csc \frac{3 \pi}{4}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{2} \pi^{2}}{8} \\
I_{3}&=\frac{\pi^2}{24}\left(\csc \frac{\pi}{6}+2 \csc \frac{3 \pi}{6}+\csc \frac{5 \pi}{6}\right)=\frac{\pi^{2}}{4} \\
I_{4}&=\frac{\pi^2}{32} \left[\left(\begin{array}{l}
3 \\
0
\end{array}\right) \csc \frac{\pi}{8}+\left(\begin{array}{l}
3 \\
1
\end{array}\right) \csc \frac{3 \pi}{8}+\left(\begin{array}{l}
3 \\
2
\end{array}\right) \csc \frac{5 \pi}{8}+\left(\begin{array}{l}
3 \\
3
\end{array}\right) \csc \frac{6\pi}{8}\right]= \frac{\pi^2}8\sqrt{10-\sqrt2}
\end{aligned}